# last digit is off by 1 regardless of math methods used

Tags: python, rounding, integer-arithmetic

Having a minor issue with the return value of this function for large parameters (works fine for smaller ones). Here is the code:

```
def pyramid_blocks(n, m, h):
  return int(h*n*m + (h*h-h)*(3*n+3*m+2*h-1)/6)
```

Here is the test case where it fails:

```
ARGUMENTS: 2123377, 2026271, 2437
EXPECTED: 10497605327499753
RETURNED: 10497605327499754
```

I know the formula is correct (subtracting 1 will make it incorrect), but the last digit keeps rounding up. Smells like a integer arithmetic bit issue. Tried using math.ceil and still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your division by 6, which is using the floating point `/` operator.  You want to use the integer division operator `//`.

```
>>> n = 2123377
>>> m = 2026271
>>> h = 2437

>>> n*m*h + (h*h-h)*(3*n+3*m+2*h-1)//6
10497605327499753
```

Answer (score 2):

Integers are exact in Python. You can use integer division with a double slash: `//`:

```
def pyramid_blocks(n, m, h):
  return int(h*n*m + (h*h-h)*(3*n+3*m+2*h-1)//6)
```

This now returns 10497605327499753

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to use integer division:

```
def pyramid_blocks(n, m, h):
  return int(h*n*m + (h*h-h)*(3*n+3*m+2*h-1)//6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Floor division(`//`) will solve your problem. This just simply removes the numbers after the decimal.

Eg:

```
>>>20/3
>>>6.666666
>>>20//3
>>>6
```

Updated code:

```
def pyramid_blocks(n, m, h):
  return int(h*n*m + (h*h-h)*(3*n+3*m+2*h-1)//6)
pyramid_blocks(2123377,2026271,2437)
```

Output(for given arguements):

```
10497605327499753
```

Answer (score 1):

The first answer solves the problem, but in case you're wondering [why this is happening](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html):

```
from decimal import *
def pyramid_blocks(n, m, h):
    n = Decimal(n)
    m = Decimal(m)
    h = Decimal(h)
    return int(h*n*m + (h*h-h)*(3*n+3*m+2*h-1)/6)

pyramid_blocks(2123377,2026271,2437)
```

Output

```
10497605327499753
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already multiple answers how to fix your problem, but no one has yet to answered why this happens. It is *not* integer arithmetic, it is *floating point* arithmetic!

10497605327499753 in binary is a number with 54 binary digits. If we ignore the leading 1 (which is not actually represented in memory) that leaves 53 digits - one more than the mantissa (or significand) of an [IEEE 754 double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) allows!